# "I wasn't hoping you do."

Tags: grammar

I am writing a scene where a girl tells a guy: "I don't have feelings for you."
He replies: "I wasn't hoping you do."
Is this a correct way to put it, "wasn't hoping you do?" It's past plus present simple. Or perhaps it should be, "I wasn't hoping you would."

Comment: It strikes me as an unusual sentence, but I think _I wasn't hoping you did_ would be more idiomatic.

Comment: "That wasn't my hope." might be better, but my instinct says it might be a little "nerdy" and so possibly wrong for the background of the character?

Comment: Thank you guys! Greatly appreciated!